# Asking for explanation some parts of the code

Tags: javascript

I was given this test to solve it, and I solve it, the test was asking for returning the sum of digits, and that's kind of easy to return it, but the catch was to return it (***If the number is negative, the first digit should count as negative***)
for example.

```
let output = sumDigits(1148);
   console.log(output); // --> 14  

   let output = sumDigits(-316);
   console.log(output); // --> 4
```

like I said I solve it like that

```js
const sumDigits = num => {
  let ar = num.toString().split('')  //Stringify the num and convert it to an array

  let minSum = 0 // initialize the minSum counter and set to the value of 0
  let plsSum = 0 // initialize the plsSum counter and set to the value of 0

  //checking if the array start with '-', and if it's i'm going to remove it.
  if (ar[0] === '-') {
    ar.splice(0, 1)
    ar.reduce((a, b) => minSum = Math.abs(a - b)) // subtracting the arrray of numbers and convet it to number after removing the first char.
  }

  // iterate over the array.
  for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    // adding the sum of array numbers to the initial var and convert it to a number
    plsSum += Number(ar[i])
  }

  //returning the minSum and plsSum
  if (minSum) {
    return minSum
  } else {
    return plsSum
  }

}

let output = sumDigits(1148)
console.log(output) // --> 14

let output2 = sumDigits(-316)
console.log(output2) // --> 4
```

but while I was searching I found this code in one line with reduce, and some of this code I couldn't understand it, that is why I'm asking you guys.
here is the code

```
const sumDigits = num =>String(num).split('').reduce((a,v,idx,arr)=> v === '-' ? (v = 0, arr[idx+1] *= -1, a + +v) :a+ +v,0)
```

so let's break it down.

`String(num).split('')`  in this part they string it and convert it to an array. ✔

`reduce((a,v,idx,arr)`  in this part they initialized reduce with 4 arguments. ✔

`v === '-' ?` in this part, they checking if the `v` is equal to `'-'`, but the question is `v` would start at **1**  in the first **output (1148)**
and it would start with 3 in the second **output (-316)**, because `a` would start with **1** and with **'-'**,  right?
then they set the **(v = 0)**.
and then they multiply `arr[idx+1] *= -1` by **-1**  my question is why?
And if someone doesn't mind explaining the rest of the code, it would be so appreciated.
Thanks an advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.abs` and convert the number to string before splitting and then use reduce to calculate the sum. Before returning  from the function check if the input is less or greater than 0 and accordingly take steps

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  // toString will convert to string so an array of string can be created
  const sum = Math.abs(num).toString().split('').reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // converting string to number before adding with previous digit
    // else it will do string concatenation instead of mathematical addition
    acc += +curr;
    return acc
  }, 0);
  return num < 0 ? -1 * sum : sum;
}



let output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14  

let outpu2t = sumDigits(-316);
console.log(outpu2t); // --> -10
```

Comment: your code should returns `sumDigits(-316)` //--> `4`  but it returns  `-10`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `arr[idx+1] *= -1` to directly manipulate the next member in the array to a negative integer.

You can try the following code on a Javascript Playground to see the value of the variables per loop steps for better understanding:
(it's the expanded version of the code you are trying to understand)

```js
function sum(num) {
  s = String(num)
    .split('')
    .reduce(function (a, v, idx, arr) {
      console.log('a=', a, 'v=', v, 'idx=', idx, 'arr=', arr);
      if (v === '-') {
        v = 0;
        arr[idx + 1] *= -1;
        a += +v;
      } else {
        a += +v;
      }
      return a;
    }, 0);
  return s;
}
console.log(sum(1148));
console.log(sum(-316));
```

Comment: Thank you @kevin.bui, for your explanation 

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus me into the part of the reduce method.
The reduce Array method can recive two arguments, the first one indicates the callback that will "reduce" the array, this callback can recive 4 arguments:

1. Acumulator
2. Current Value
3. Current Index
4. Array

the second argument of the reduce method indicates with which value will start the **Acumulator** argument of the callback.

Once explained that, in the sample that you have seen, he indicates that the **Acumulator** will start with 0 value:

```
.reduce(<...>, 0)
```

Then, in the first iteration of the reduce method, the first value of **Current Value** will be the 0 indexed value of the array.

If we consider the case where `num` is `-316`, then:

- First iteration:
  The callback variables will be:

  ```
  a = 0
  v = '-'
  idx = 0
  arr = ['-', '3', '1', '6']
  ```

  The proccess will be:

  ```
  v === '-' //true, then:
  v = 0
  arr[idx+1] *= -1 //here, he are converting the value next to the sign to a negative value
  a + +v //then, he add the v value to the acumulator with the corresponding sign.
  ```
- Second iteration:
  Callback variables

  ```
   a = 0
   v = -3
   idx = 1
   arr = ['-', -3, '1', '6']
  ```

  Process:

  ```
  v === '-' //false, then:
  a + +v //a = 0, v = -3. 0 + +(-3) = -3 (Number)
  ```

And I think that you can decifrate the rest of the story.

Comment: Thank you @Alejandro Gomez, your explanation is very detailed thanks, man 